# Получить даные из таблицы с джоином на другую где id НЕ присутствуют

Tags: join, mysql

Вопрос туповат

Есть две табицы - Клиенты и Менджеры

В первой (**customers**) куча инфы и ключ **customer_id**

Во второй(**manager_clients** ) **customer_id** и **manager_id**

Так вот мне нужно получить смежную таблицу всех клиентов, которые НЕ занесены во второй таблице

**Например первая таблица**

```
customer_id =1 name=customer
customer_id =2 name=customer
customer_id =3 name=customer
```

**Вторая**

```
customer_id =2 manager_id =1
```

В результате запроса должно вывести клиентов с id 1,3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать что-то вроде:

```
select * from CUSTOMERS
  where customer_id not in (select customer_id from MANAGER_CLIENTS);
```

Comment: Бред и ужас. Результат Вас сильно удивит. Что-то вроде

    select c.customer_id from CUSTOMERS c
    where not exists (select * from MANAGER_CLIENTS mc 
      where c.customer_id = mc.customer_id)

Comment: Проверил, обдумал - Вы правы! 
Смутил сам вопрос: "получить данные с джоином". Предложил более простой вариант без join.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Почитал ман по not exist и не совсем его понял, он выполняется если подзапрос ничего не вернул?

Comment: Да, верно! Если подзапрос не возвращает ни одной строки, тогда оператор NOT EXISTS вернет true и наоборот.